# Script to connect with ssh to remote server with password

Tags: shell-script, ssh, suse

I'm connecting from one remote machine to many remote machines within one network. Username and password for all remote machines is the same. I want to write a script that will use my username and pass to login to machine. I can't install any tool on host machine (expect or sshpass). Copying public key to target remote machine doesn't make a sense since I rarely connect more than once to the same machine. Everyday - new machines.

Is it possible to set up ssh on host machine to be able to connect to remote machines without need to set something on target machines?

Local machine that I'm using to connect to the rest of the network - **SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3**

Comment: Using keys is the proper way to do it, but you can do it in a very insecure and non-recommended way by writing directly the password into the script using sshpass:  $ sshpass -p <password> ssh user@hostname

Comment: Can you install software on your own machine, the one which connects to the "one" remote machine that connects to the "many"?

Comment: @icarus, yes I can install software on my local machine that I'm using to connect to intermediate remote machine to reach target hosts.

Comment: @Zumo de Vidrio, is this a correct syntax?

`#!/bin/bash
ssh $1
sshpass -p _pass_ ssh user@$1`

Comment: @V.Plagov I just tried with: sshpass -p '<password>' ssh user@hostname and it works, remember to put the password between ' ' characters, I missed that in my previous comment.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio, hmm... strange. I set password between ' ', but target host still asks for password. What is sshpass in your example? I don't sure it is installed on host and target machines.

Comment: @V.Plagov I don't have it on the target machine, just in my host. sshpass is the command, not a password. For example:  
    $  sshpass -p 'my_password' ssh root@my_host

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio, have you installed sshpass on local machine separately of ssh? Looks like I don't have sshpass on remote host (from where I'm connecting to targets) and I don't have rights to install it.

Comment: @V.Plagov Of course, I have installed sshpass and ssh separately, I missed that! I was thinking that you were trying to connect directly from your own PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51157/discussion-between-v-plagov-and-zumo-de-vidrio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the requirements I would install `expect` on my local machine and use it to add in effect a new command. Let us call the remote hosts `one` and `many1`, `many2` and the local machine `mybox`. Something like this (untested)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# connect to "one"
spawn ssh username@one
# next lines shouldn't be needed, should have shared keys for "one"
expect "assword: "
# provide password for "one", ending with "\r"
send -- "the_password_for_username@one\r"
# mainloop
interact "~p" {
    send "ssh manyuser@[lindex $argv 0]\r"
    expect "yes/no)? " { send "yes\r" exp_continue } "assword: "
    send "the_password_for_many\r"
    }
```

Run this on `mybox` as `./script many1`, it will connect you to `one`

Then when you want to connect to `many1` just type `~p`. It will run the ssh command, answer the "do you want to connect" question if asked, and provide the password.

Of course the standard comments about the insecurity of storing passwords in scripts apply. The other slight downside is that you need to dedicate a key sequence to this. Here I am using `~p` but you could use a function key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But sorry, I'm not sure I have understand it. Where should I run that script? On `mybox` or on `one`? And what should I write in here `"seek the one true way\r"` and here `"go out to the many\r"`?

Comment: thank you. How should I run this script on `mybox`? How to pass to the script address of target host?

Comment: Install expect on `mybox`, and add the script. As written the script expects that you were always running `ssh username@one`, edit the third line accordingly. either make the script executable or run `expect -f scriptname`. If  the `one` host varies or the username varies then we need more code to pass them in.

Comment: can we continue in chat? Since I'm completely confused...

Comment: Yes, I don't have enough reputation to open chat, so if you can make it - I will be very thankful :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51161/discussion-between-icarus-and-v-plagov).